# Does iOS trigger CXEndCallAction without any user interaction?

Tags: ios, callkit

Sometimes CXEndCallAction is triggered by either iOS or the user. Is it possible for iOS to trigger it due to the low battery or any other reason?

Thanks in advance for the answers.